# Upload widget does not work - Dynamic form Yii2 starter kit

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, dynamicform, yii2-active-records

iam using the widget (trntv\filekit\widget \ Upload) of yii2-starter-kit, implement the use of the dynamic form (wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget), the problem is that the upload widget works only on the first element, when adding Other items fail to load correctly

_form

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'dynamic-form']); ?>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-6">

        <?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>


        <?php echo $form->field($model, 'category_id')->dropDownList(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(
            $categories,
            'id',
            'name'
        ), ['prompt' => '']) ?>



        <?= $form->field($model, 'amount')->textInput() ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'delivery_charge')->textInput() ?>

        <?php echo $form->field($model, 'description')->widget(
            \yii\imperavi\Widget::class,
            [
                'plugins' => ['fullscreen', 'fontcolor', 'video'],
                'options' => [
                    'minHeight' => 200,
                    'maxHeight' => 200,
                    'buttonSource' => true,
                    'convertDivs' => false,
                    'removeEmptyTags' => true,
                    'imageUpload' => Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/file/storage/upload-imperavi']),
                ],
            ]
        ) ?>


    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">

        <?php echo $form->field($model, 'attachments')->widget(
            Upload::class,
            [
                'url' => ['/file/storage/upload'],
                'maxFileSize' => 5000000, // 5 MiB,
                'acceptFileTypes' => new JsExpression('/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i'),
            ]
        );
        ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'availability')->widget(SwitchInput::className()); ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'status')->dropDownList(\common\models\Product::statuses()) ?>



        <?php echo $form->field($model, 'features')->widget(
            \yii\imperavi\Widget::class,
            [
                'plugins' => ['fullscreen', 'fontcolor', 'video'],
                'options' => [
                    'minHeight' => 200,
                    'maxHeight' => 200,
                    'buttonSource' => true,
                    'convertDivs' => false,
                    'removeEmptyTags' => true,
                    'imageUpload' => Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/file/storage/upload-imperavi']),
                ],
            ]
        ) ?>

    </div>

</div>


<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-10">

        <?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
            'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
            'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
            'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
            'limit' => 10, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
            'min' => 1, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
            'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class
            'deleteButton' => '.remove-item', // css class
            'model' => $modelsIngredient[0],
            'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
            'formFields' => [
                'title',
                'description',
                'image',
                'featured_base_url',
                'featured_path'
            ],
        ]); ?>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> Product Ingredients
                <button type="button" class="pull-right add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add
                </button>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body container-items">
                <!-- widgetContainer -->
                <?php foreach ($modelsIngredient

                    as $index => $modelIngredient) : ?>
                    <div class="item panel panel-default">
                        <!-- widgetBody -->
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <span class="panel-title-address">Ingredients: <?= ($index + 1) ?></span>
                            <button type="button" class="pull-right remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <?php
                            // necessary for update action.
                            if (!$modelIngredient->isNewRecord) {
                                echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelIngredient, "[{$index}]id");
                            }
                            ?>

                            <div class="col-md-12">

                                <?php echo $form->field($modelIngredient, "[{$index}]title")->textInput(); ?>

                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                

                                <?php echo $form->field($modelIngredient, "[{$index}]image")->widget(
                                    Upload::class,
                                    [
                                        'url' => ['/file/storage/upload'],
                                        'maxFileSize' => 5000000, // 5 MiB,
                                        'acceptFileTypes' => new JsExpression('/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i'),
                                    ]
                                );
                                ?>

                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12">


                            <?php echo $form->field($modelIngredient, "[{$index}]description")->textarea(); ?>

                

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>

    </div>

  </div>


  </div>


 <div class="form-group">
    

  <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update',    ['class'=>'btnbtnprimary'])      ?>
 

 </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); 


   $js = '
    jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {

    jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper .panel-title-address").each(function(index) {

    jQuery(this).html("Ingredients: " + (index + 1))
    });
    });

   jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterDelete", function(e) {
   jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper .panel-title-address").each(function(index) {
   jQuery(this).html("Ingredients: " + (index + 1))
   });
   });
  ';




   $this->registerJs($js);
   ?>
```

only first one is working the second one not working the value get null in controller.also second one css and js also not working.

[image]

Comment: any one know???